# Java polymorphism through injection at runtime

Tags: java, polymorphism, code-injection

I hear that in Java I can achieve polymorphism through injection at runtime. Can someone please show a simple example of how that is done? I search online but I can't find anything: maybe I am searching wrong. So I know about polymorphism through interface and and extension such as

```
class MyClass extends Parent implements Naming
```

in such case I am achieving polymorphism twice: MyClass is at once of type `Parent` and `Naming`. But I don't get how injection works. The idea is that I would not be using the `@Override` keyword during injection. I hope the question is clear. Thanks.

So the end result here, per my understanding, is to change the behavior of a method through injection instead of by `@Override` it during development.

Comment: *"...in such case I am achieving polymorphism twice: MyClass is at once of type Parent and Naming"* That's not what "polymorphism" means. I can see how you got there, but that's not what it means. You might want to look into some OOP tutorials.

Comment: Polymorphism isn't something that can reasonably be explained in an SO comment, which is why I suggested a tutorial.

Comment: Where do you hear it? Some website (if so please provide the link)? Or somebody told it to you without explaining any further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I know about polymorphism through interface and and extension such as
>
> `class MyClass extends Parent implements Naming`

This is known as inhertiance and not polymorphism. `MyClass`is a `Parent` and `MyClass` is also a `Naming`. That being said, `inheritance` allows you to achive `polymorphism`.

Consider a class other than`MyClass` that also implements `Naming` :

```
class SomeOtherClass implements Naming {
     @Override
     public void someMethodDefinedInTheInterface() {

     }
 }
```

Now consider a method that takes a `Naming` argument somewhere in your code base :

```
public void doSomething(Naming naming) {
     naming.someMethodDefinedInTheInterface();
}
```

The `doSomething` method can be passed an instance of any `class` that implements `Naming`. So both the following calls are valid :

```
doSomething(new MyClass());//1
doSomething(new SomeOtherClass());//2
```

Observe how you can call `doSomething` with different parameters. At runtime, the first call will call `someMethodDefinedInTheInterface` from `MyClass` and the second call will call `someMethodDefinedInTheInterface` from `SomeOtherClass`. This is known as `runtime-polymorphism` which can be achieved through inheritance.

> But I don't get how injection works. The idea is that I would not be using the @Override keyword during injection

That's true in the broader sense. To `inject` something into a class, the class should ideally favor `composition` over `inheritance`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) answer that does a good job in explaining the reason for favoring composition over inheritance.

To extend the above example from my answer, let's modify the `doSomething` method as follows :

```
  public class ClassHasANaming {
      private Naming naming;

      public ClassHasANaming(Naming naming) {
          this.naming = naming;
      }

      public void doSomething() {
           naming.someMethodDefinedInTheInterface();
      }
  }
```

Observe how `ClassHasANaming` now has-a `Naming` dependency that can be **injected** from the outside world :

```
ClassHasANaming callMyClass = new ClassHasANaming(new MyClass());
callMyClass.doSomething();
```

If you use the [Factory pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm), you can actually chose which subclass gets instantiated at runtime.

Do you think we could have done what we did above using `inheritance`?

```
 public class ClassIsANaming implements Naming {
    public void doSomething() {
        someMethodDefinedInTheInterface();
    }

    @Override
    public void someMethodDefinedInTheInterface() {
        //....
    }
 }
```

The answer is **No**. `ClassIsANaming` is bound to a single implementation of the `someMethodDefinedInTheInterface` method at compile time itself.
       `

Answer (score 1):

Taking a contrived example. You have a class `Store` that stores things:

```
class Store {

    private List l

    void store(Object o) {
       l.add(o);
    }

    void setStoreProvider(List l) {
        this.l = l
    }
}
```

You can inject the actual `List` used as the backing storage using `setStoreProvider` which could be a linked list, array backed list, whatever.

Hence, depending on the injected type your `Store` class would have the features of the injected type (with regards to memory usage, speed, etc).

This is a kind of polymorphism without the class implementing an interface.

Comment: `List` is polymorphic here, not `Store`. `Store` is just a client using a (polymorphic) interface. `Store` would be polymorphic if `DatabaseStore` extended it overriding the `store` method to add object to a database for example.

Comment: I knew someone would raise this. Store is implementing polymorphic behaviour, even though it is not Polymorphic according to normal Java definitions. In the end, an superclass with subclasses works the same way internally (more or less) as the Store and List combination.